# Applying for a UK visitor visa from Australia

Tags: visas, uk, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds, proof-of-ties

I am a Russian citizen currently living in Australia on a temporary working visa. I want to visit my boyfriend in the UK and I have some concerns about my application.
First of all, I'm unemployed. I have graduated from a university and want to travel a bit while I have some free time. I have enough savings to pay for my trip, but no job or regular income. What is the best way to approach this?

Also, would it be better not to mention that I have a boyfriend in the UK, because it would look like I'm planning to stay (no ties to my home country or country of residence)? At the moment I'm planning to write in my application that I want to visit a friend and I'm going to stay at his place. Would it improve my chances of getting a visa if he sends me an invitation or a letter of sponsorship?

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer with any degree of certainty. TSE advice is always to tell the truth in any visa application. There are many questions on TSE regarding UK visa applications, including questions similar to your own. Having a sponsor doesn’t necessarily improve your chances; without a job and ties to your home/country of residence your application would be weak.